# How to execute commands in docker container as part of bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I would like to write a bash script that automates the following:

Get inside running container

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME /bin/bash
```

Execute some commands:

```
cat /dev/null > /usr/local/tomcat/logs/app.log
exit
```

The problematic part is when `docker exec` is executed. The new shell is created, but the other commands are not executed.

Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `heredoc` with `docker exec` command:

```
docker exec -i CONTAINER_NAME bash <<'EOF'
cat /dev/null > /usr/local/tomcat/logs/app.log
exit
EOF
```

To use variables:

```
logname='/usr/local/tomcat/logs/app.log'
```

then use as:

```
docker exec -i CONTAINER_NAME bash <<EOF
cat /dev/null > "$logname"
exit
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks. This works.
How can I pass parameters from outside to heredoc?

Comment: To pass parameters use `EOF` instead of `'EOF'` at first line and then use variables inside heredoc

Comment: For those wondering, I successfully got this to work with the `docker run` command as well.

Comment: @ndmeiri how?? I am trying with ``docker run --detach-keys="ctrl-p" -it busybox`` and I can't make it work

Answer (score -3):

You can simply launch

`docker exec -it container_id cat /dev/null > /usr/local/tomcat/logs/app.log`