# Ubunto docker sh mysql script run

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell, docker

I have a script which build my docker env.
I have this line:

```
docker exec -it guac-mysql /bin/bash
mysql -u root -p123456
CREATE DATABASE guacamole;
CREATE USER 'guacamole' IDENTIFIED BY 123456;
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON guacamole.* TO 'guacamole';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
quit
```

When I run, the script gets in the bash on the container, but the other lines dont run, I just have to run them one by one.
How can I exec and then inject the script?

Thanks :)

Comment: See: [How to execute commands in docker container as part of bash shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36627980/3776858)

Comment: mysql: command not found

Answer (score 0):

you can't run this as a single script. the docker exec command will create a shell into the container. it won't run the rest of it until you exit the container. then it will run the `mysql` etc...

you need to run `docker exec -it guac-mysql /bin/bash`

and then you can create a separate script to run the `mysql` command within the container itself

but your current script won't work. again, it will run `mysql` and then wait for that to exit before running the `create database`, etc.

see the docs on executing scripts from a file: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-batch-commands.html